# Bypass "Entity not found" error with JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Sometimes it's quite difficult (or a performance problem) to clean delete all references to an entity.

For example, I've got a Person object which has relationships to another Person objects.

When I delete a Person, I don't want to delete this Person in all relations she can have simply because sometimes this Person object does not know where it is referenced. So, if I would like to clean delete all references, I must do extra sql work that can result in performance problem.

In an ideal world, I would like to delete the Person object and when another Person do a reference to this Person (because it has its id in its relations), simply return null.

The fact is JPA complains that

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: No row with the given identifier exists
```

Is there a way to force JPA to return a null reference and not an exception in this case ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can use the [@NotFound](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFound.html) annotation with the value `NotFoundAction.IGNORE`, which will return null if an associated entity doesn't exist.

A word of caution: if you use this in a collections and hibernate doesn't find one of the entries, it will add a null value in the collection, which is very annoying. To avoid this, you can wrap the collection in a Collection that skips nulls.

Comment: that was exactly what I was searching ! Thank you so much. This is hibernate specific, isn't it ?

Comment: I'm glad it helped and yes, the annotation is hibernate specific

Comment: @Augusto Why is Spring Data throwing this exception at the first place?

Comment: @svlada. It's because there's a *soft* foreign key, which is not enforced. So a table A has a column where an id of table B is stored, but there's no row on table B with that primary key. This is usually the case when foreign keys are not enforced. So if someone get this, it means that the relational database is not used correctly.

Comment: When I add the hibernate-annotations to my java project, my war can not be deployed Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory:      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: This is a Hibernate annotation, in JPA you can not do this.

Answer (score 5):

No, at least nothing standard (JPA)

But you can control what happens with these association using the `cascade` attribute ot `@*ToMany` and `@*ToOne` annotations.

Answer (score 3):

You'd use @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE) 
this will skip null entities.
BUT (as Augusto said) if you are using for example Primefaces Datatable and get 10 rows and skipped 2,
because of the @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE) in your property, 
you will have 10 rows and not 8 (ghost rows actually).

```
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private Product p;
```

Answer (score -3):

```
ERROR 1452: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails....
   if this type of error occur :
   then
  First of all
  goto this table and check in setting > if Engine is: InnoDB then change its to MyISAM

 (and delete references foreign constraint)
```

Its 100% working...

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?